# Sometimes zypper doesn't locate packages when it is provided with the filename only

Tags: zypper

If the command is provided the full path, the expected package is found:

```
> zypper search --provides --match-exact /usr/sbin/update-ca-certificates
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...

S  | Name            | Summary                                               | Type
---+-----------------+-------------------------------------------------------+--------
i+ | ca-certificates | Utilities for system wide CA certificate installation | package
```

While it isn't if it is just provided with the filename only:

```
> zypper search --provides --match-exact update-ca-certificates
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
No matching items found.
```

But it works with the filename only for `bash` as shown:

```
> zypper search --provides --match-exact bash
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...

S | Name | Summary                    | Type
--+------+----------------------------+--------
i | bash | The GNU Bourne-Again Shell | package
```

So, is this a bug?, or am I just missing something to locate the `ca-certificates` package looking by the filename `update-ca-certificates`?.

Answer (score 0):

from the `zypper` manual:

```
-x, --match-exact
    Searches for an exact name of the package.
```

so `zypper` is searching for the **package** name. It also happens to work for exact filenames (full paths).

You are being confused since you think that by specifying **bash** `zypper` is finding `/usr/bin/bash`, but in reality `zypper` is finding the **package-name** bash.